# How to play full movie clip once with a single key press

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a movie clip (lets say 10 frame with 10 different image) and I am playing it with a keyboard. so player has to hold down the key to play that movie clip if player release the button it stops doing the movie clip and go to normal.

```
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event; 

var dPressed:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN , keyDownHandaler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP , KeyUpHandaler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , gameLoop);

function keyDownHandaler(Devent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
        if (Devent.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
            {
                dPressed = true;
            }
}

function KeyUpHandaler (Uevent:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    if (Uevent.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        {
            dPressed = false;
            char.gotoAndStop("Standby Mode");
        }

function gameLoop(Levent:Event):void
{
    if (dPressed)
        {
            char.x += 5;

            char.gotoAndStop("Char Move Right");
        }
```

That's working fine but what I need is not hold the key, player will press the key 1 time and it will finish the whole movie clip once (lets say 5 frame with 5 different image) and go back to standby mode instead of looping.

I have tried `char.gotoAndPlay("Frame name")` // which content the 5 frame movie clip

but it doesn't work, when I click it goes to the first frame and stays like that.

Comment: If I understand what you'd like to say correctly you just need to put " dPressed = false;" at the "stand by" frame instead of "KeyUpHandaler"

Comment: As per the code you posted you dont need to use 'KeyUpHandaler' method and add some condition in gameLoop method or script on the 5th frame of your movieclip to take it back to 'stand by mode'

Comment: i get your logic  Sameer Jain thanks a lot