# how to make full jump with single press

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is a very simple question but even after googling i am not getting the right idea.

i have a hero who i want to make jump. i have written the code in my logic but the problem is i have to hold the key to perform the whole jump. lets say it will go `y-= 20`but if i hold my button its going the full distance. But if i click once its not going/ passing the full distance.

i want to make my hero jump the whole way with a single press, i mean just 1 press not holding down the button.

here is my code

```
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

var grav:int = 0;
var floor = 450;
var jumping:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN , keyDownHandaler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP , KeyUpHandaler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , update);

function gravity ():void
    {
        hero.y += grav;
        if (hero.y+hero.height/2 <floor){
            grav++;
        }

        else {
            grav = 0;
            hero.y = floor - hero.height/2 ;

            }

    }


function keyDownHandaler(Devent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
        if (Devent.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
            {
                jumping = true;
            }
}

function KeyUpHandaler (Uevent:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    if (Uevent.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
        {
            jumping = false;
        }
}

function update(Levent:Event):void
{
    if (jumping)
        {
            hero.y -= 20;
        }

gravity();

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play full movie clip once with a single key press](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101017/how-to-play-full-movie-clip-once-with-a-single-key-press)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added because the first answer is already pretty long.  This is an answer with the requested re-write of the OP's code:  (Read notes at the end)

```
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

var grav:double = 0.025;  //Change this to make gravity stronger or weaker.
var gravInc:double = .2;  //Changed to "double" because int is too large an increment.  If double doesn't work, try float or decimal.
var floor = 450;
var jumping:Boolean = false;


stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN , keyDownHandaler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP , KeyUpHandaler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , update);



    function gravity ():void
    {
        if (hero.y+hero.height/2 < floor){
            //grav++;  //not needed
            gravInc = gravInc - grav;  //GravInc starts strong, and gradually decreases.  It will eventully be less than zero, and start negetive.
            hero.y -= gravInc;  //The effect of which is the chracter will move upward until gravity takes over, and make hero move downward - increaseing speed until it hits the floor.
        } else {
            //grav = 0;  Not needed
            hero.y = floor - hero.height/2 ;
            //We've hit the floor.  Stop jump sequence
            jumping = false;
        }
    }


function keyDownHandaler(Devent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
        if (Devent.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
            {
                if (jumping==false) {  //The character is not already jumping
                    //This initiates the jump sequence
                    //set up the jump sequence by resetting the gravInc and setting jumping to true
                    gravInc = .2;
                    jumping = true;

                    //Start the jump now so that the character is off the floor
                    hero.y -= gravInc;
                }
            }
}

function KeyUpHandaler (Uevent:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    if (Uevent.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
        {
//            jumping = false;
//            Not needed here
        }
}

function update(Levent:Event):void
{
  //  This whole thing goes.  It is not needed because the jumping==true will handle it.
  //  if (jumping)
  //      {
  //          hero.y -= 20;
  //      }

    if ( jumping==true ){ 
        gravity(); 
    }

}
```

I have no way of testing this code.  I commented out the parts of your code that were unnecessary, and I added in the things that you'd need to make it function.

ActionScript syntax is very similar to JavaScript.  So I'm including this link as a sort-of demo to show how the whole gravity thing works in an actual program.  [Bounding balls](http://dpoisn.com/demos/bounce/)

View the source on that page.

Hopefully this does the trick for you.

Comment: Wow , it works just fine .This code has some mistake but as you tell me you could not check it so i modified it as i needed and it works. Thanks you very very much

Comment: Glad to hear.  Glad it worked.  :)  I've written that sort of routine SO many times.  In many different languages.  So I saw what you were trying to do, and saw where you were off track.  I just hope you learned something from it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the trick you need to work out is keeping the "jumping" flag set until the entire jump sequence is finished.  Currently you have it resetting as soon as the button lifts up, then setting again when it's re-pressed.
There is actually no reason to turn off the jumping flag just because the user lifted the button.

Right here:

```
hero.y += grav;
        if (hero.y+hero.height/2 <floor){
            grav++;
        }
```

You have a check to see if the character has hit the floor.  It should be there that the jump sequence finishes.

All the stuff you do to your character should not be tracked on the KEY being DOWN.  It should be tracked on the jumping=true.  The key being pressed just starts the sequence.  And you do need to keep that flag so as not to start the sequence again if it's already running.

Comment: Thank you for answering but sorry to say i am still not getting the idea. Can you plz do this in my fla file 

here is the file 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By4vnFn0J42xT09FTEN3cEt5LVk/view?usp=sharing

thanks again

Comment: I do not even have a version of Flash to open that.  Sorry.  But the explanation is there.  The behavior you are looking for is to start and end a sequence.  You have the start correct.  But your end is in the wrong place.  That's what I'm describing.

Comment: i think i am understanding your logic but i am not understanding what code i use and where.

Comment: If you would like me to modify your code and post another answer I can.  Although, I have no way to test it.  All I could do is steer you the right way.

Comment: Sure why not , it will be a great help if you try.